# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to listen to abstract unix socket "/containerd ... permission denied: unknown

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I installed Docker on Ubuntu 18 by:

> sudo snap install docker

Created docker group, add my user to it. Now try to test by:

> docker container run hello-world

and receive an error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to listen to abstract unix
>   socket
>   "/containerd-shim/moby/abcfbe6936523635f7064c99e32321e30dd4628ff3b9496493566da1d1e5ab40/shim.sock":
>   listen unix
>   /containerd-shim/moby/abcfbe6936523635f7064c99e32321e30dd4628ff3b9496493566da1d1e5ab40/shim.sock:
>   bind: permission denied: unknown.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the following.
Remove this installation:

> sudo snap remove docker

May also remove:

> sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io

Then:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt install docker.io

To run at startup:

> sudo systemctl start docker
>
> sudo systemctl enable docker

Restart Ubuntu. All works.

To add group and user if neccessary:

> sudo groupadd docker
>
> sudo usermod -aG docker your_user

and restart.

Answer (score 1):

I got this message, and it turned out that there were containerd processes still running that were no longer controlled by docker.

```
29115 ?        Sl     0:00 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/17d9aefe0d782a651d0f5a064fb0c86c0129837bace89863757419b2cd
29131 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ runc init
24884 ?        Sl     0:00 containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/01570af76d634eb0885f750dcad064b7c3288fdb2b2d1f9041aa4f2ca3
24900 ?        Ssl    0:00  \_ runc init
```

I just needed to kill them and then I restarted dockerd for good measure, and did not need to uninstall docker or anything drastic like that.